# Checked checkbox not sending value with $_POST foreach

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have a PHP mailer form with this in the code:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $querydetails = $querydetails  . '<li>' .  $key . ': ' . $value . ' </li>';
}
```

Simple right? Works as normal for text inputs but not checkboxes.

I have this for the checkboxes in the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fsfnew" value="I'd like x!">
<input type="checkbox" name="fsfused" value="I need y!">
```

If I check just one checkbox, **both** keys get sent through, but no value.

If I check no checkboxes, I get both keys sent through without values.

If I check all checkboxes, I get both keys sent through without values.

This should be simple, and I have been at it for hours and can't work it out.

Comment: Your code seems correct. Can you pest your used <form> tag here.

Comment: Checkboxes get posted only when they are checked. So, irrespective of how many checkboxes are there, only those will get posted which have been checked.

Comment: The problem is, unchecked boxes are also coming through the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an HTML table for checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxArray[]" value="I'd like x!" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxArray[]" value="I need y!" />
```

And then in your php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['myCheckboxArray'] && is_array($_POST['myCheckboxArray']) {
    foreach ($_POST['myCheckboxArray'] as $key) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if I am using a Label to style the checkboxes, which I need to do unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think that using a label makes any difference. Can you explain please what do you mean?